# jQuery: add class on current element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add class on my li element.I want to add class on click. when I click  on button its add css class on current li . Like when I click first time then it's active first time. after second click it's active on second li,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("li:first").addClass("intro");
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.intro {
    font-size: 150%;
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<li>This is a heading</li>
<li>This is a heading</li>
<li>This is a heading</li>
<li>This is a heading</li>
<li>This is a heading</li>
<li>This is a heading</li>
<li>This is a heading</li>
<li>This is a heading</li>


<button>Add a class name to the first p element</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of just about everything

Comment: What should be your `active` element? I see no `.active` or anything in your code

Comment: What should happen clicking the button 10 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the click event and apply with `eq()` .And `li` length is `8` .so apply condition after 7 reach ,count reset to 0

```js
var c = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    if (c > 7) {
      c = 0;
    }
    $("li").removeClass('intro')
    $("li").eq(c).addClass("intro");
    c++;

  });
});
```

```css
.intro {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <h1>This is a heading</h1>

  <li class="intro">This is a heading</li>
  <li>This is a heading</li>
  <li>This is a heading</li>
  <li>This is a heading</li>
  <li>This is a heading</li>
  <li>This is a heading</li>
  <li>This is a heading</li>
  <li>This is a heading</li>


  <button>Add a class name to the first p element</button>

</body>

</html>
```

**Updated answer with `prev and next`** for slide

```js
var c = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('data') == 'next' ? c++ : c--;
    if (c > 7) {
      c = 0;
    }
    $("li").removeClass('intro')
    $("li").eq(c).addClass("intro");


  });
});
```

```css
.intro {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <h1>This is a heading</h1>

  <li class="intro">This is a heading</li>
  <li>This is a heading</li>
  <li>This is a heading</li>
  <li>This is a heading</li>
  <li>This is a heading</li>
  <li>This is a heading</li>
  <li>This is a heading</li>
  <li>This is a heading</li>


  <button data="next">next</button>
  <button data="prev">prev</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Prasad, `c = c > 7 ? 0 : c;`... we're not supposed to modify JS by adding a HTML element. Can you improve your answer to make your JS more dynamic?

Comment: prasad@ you there

Comment: Prasad , I need first Li as a active class,

Comment: @sanjay for default first li is active right.see my updated answer

Comment: ok @ and one suggetion more Dear, how can i reverse this. becouse this loop, if i have previous and next button. I am merging this code with slider

Comment: @sanjay see my upadted answer .I was added .prev next button like slide.Simply decrement the count value

Comment: Well this is awesome @ Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
       //Find the li with the active class and add your other class
       $("li.active").addClass("your-class");
    });
})
```

Here is a demo snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button").click(function(){
    $("li.active").addClass('foo-class')
  
  })
})
```

```css
.foo-class{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='active'>Active</li>
  <li> Non active</li>
</ul>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Why downvoting?Can you explain

Comment: why?Can you explain

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan have a look at my snippet

Comment: Roko C.Buljain@ if you have  good amount of connect it's not mean you have to previlage to down any script or question

Comment: @sanjay thanks .My scrip may not do what the OP wants but it is a working code

Comment: Manos Kounelakis@ many time people misunderstand the requirement, its not mean any buddy have privilege to dislike

Comment: @sanjay when an answer's JS code does not reflect OP's code - and without specifying the needed changes to make such answer work *can* attract downvotes since it's low quality. Manos added the HTML later and still did not pointed out that an initial class is required, but at least looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Find the `li` with the active class and add your other class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       // Find li and add other class
       var l=$("body").find("li:first-child");
       $(l).addClass("your-class");
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks To Improve my Answer.